# How to efficiently delete rows from an Excel XLSX file with Python

Tags: python, excel, big-o, openpyxl

With Python I need to delete from a large Excel sheet (ca. up to 100,000 rows)   many rows, then save the sheet back as Excel file. The rows I want to delete are not necessarily continues, because whether to delete a row depends on the cell value in one column.

1. My first approach was to check, then delete each necessary row starting from the top of the sheet. I used [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for this.

   This method worked sensibly only for small sheets up to 100 rows, then it became awfully slow, even deleting 900 rows from a 1000 row sheet took many minutes!
2. Now I delete from the end (still with OpenPyXL), thinking that deleting from the end avoids costly shifting of bottom cells. And indeed it works much better: 900 rows from a 1000 row sheet are deleted in under 10 seconds.

   However with larger sheets this time grows over-proportional: A 2000 rows sheet needs 30 seconds, a 4000 row sheet needs 150 seconds. So 10,000 or even 100,000 rows are totally out of the question.

**So I want to find a faster way to delete rows on large sheets.**

For the core work I use the Worksheet function [`delete_rows`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=delete_rows#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.delete_rows). Does OpenPyXL provide another method to delete rows which does not degrade on large sheets?

Or is there another Python package for modifying XLSX files with a better scaling behaviour?

---

PS: Please note, I do need to retain the original cell decorations, etc. Hence an approach which exports the sheet to, say, a dataframe and after deletion saves this back to XLSX won't work.

Comment: Deleting lots of non-contiguous rows is always going to be slow and there is no other way to do this.

Comment: @CharlieClark I understand that it will take _some_ time, but I am hoping for _proportional_ increase and not beyond that...

Comment: It's proportionate to the number of cells that have to be moved. Can't really say more without a file and theoretical discussions like this aren't much use.